# What is this end part called? What adapter do I need to attach a tank?

Tags: gas, fireplace

[image]

What is this end part called? What adapter do I need to attach a tank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called a flare fitting. It mates to a roughly cone shaped fitting (usually on a valve) which makes a metal on metal seal with pressure when the nut is screwed down on threads on the fitting. No tape or pipe dope needed or would do any good. The flared tubing is soft copper.

The size would be the OD of the copper tubing which looks like 1/2 inch or 3/8 inch.

Comment: What type of value do I need? I appreciate all the help, as this is the first time I've ever seen or delt with a gas fireplace. The home was a foreclosure too, so I figured it would be missing parts.

Comment: Don't connect it directly to a tank - you'll need a pressure regulator too.  You may want to get someone from your propane company to hook it up

Comment: Ok,Thanks. I was trying to avoid that. It's $200 for them to come out and hook it up. I was trying to avoid it, but it doesn't seem that it's avoidable.

Comment: You would use something like this https://www.lowes.com/pl/Propane-tank-regulators-with-hoses-Propane-tanks-accessories-Grills-outdoor-cooking-Outdoors/4294610335. Then you would need a fitting (double cone) to go from the end of the hose to the flare. You do not need any teflon tape or pipe dope. Since this is a foreclosure you need to check for leaks in the gas piping from this point to the burner. Spray soapy water on the joints you make and any others and look for bubbles. A GAS LEAK IS DANGEROUS.

Comment: If the line has been open for sometime you may want to consider blowing it out . Disconnect the fire place end and blow the line out. If you don't have compressed air, suck it out with a vacuum cleaner. You don't want a stray bug clogging things up.